# Struts 2: Set ID of <td> to iterator value?

Tags: java, html, struts2

I have the following code, how do I go about setting the ID of the TD equal to that of the Year that is returned from my list (iterator)?  I need this so I can then perform JavaScript functions on the table/TD (hide/show...).

```
<table id="earningtesttable">
       <s:iterator value="earningsTest">
            <tr>
               <td id=""> <!--I want to set the id also equal to the year-->
                    Year: <b><s:property value="year" /></b>
               </td>
            </tr>
       </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<td id="<s:property value="year" />">
```